# Fit a circuit figure in beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to fit this circuit in beamer presentation.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Lets unfold the box}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}{scale=0.5}

\draw (0,2.5)                   coordinate[label=above:$H$] (H)
to[short](15,2.5)               coordinate[label=above:$G$] (G)
(0,-2.5)                        coordinate[label=above:$E$] (E)
to[short](15,-2.5)              coordinate[label=above:$F$] (F)
(0,7.5)
to[short](15,7.5)
(0,-7.5)
to[short](15,-7.5)
(15,7.5)
to[short](15,-7.5)
(0,7.5)
to[short](0,-7.5)
(5,2.5)                        coordinate[label=above:$D$] (D)
to[short](5,-2.5)              coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A)
(10,2.5)                       coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C)
to[short](10,-2.5)             coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B);

\fill[orange,opacity=0.4](A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\fill[red,opacity=0.4](A)--(D)--(H)--(E)--cycle;
\fill[blue,opacity=0.4](B)--(C)--(G)--(F)--cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But it will not fit in the frame. How do I make it fit in a frame?

Comment: Change `{scale=0.5}` to `[scale=0.5]` and replace `\begin{center}...\end{center}` by `\centering`.

Comment: Actually you don't need any `\centering` at all, figures are centred by default in beamer

Comment: @Ignasi Would you like to  convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a typping problem. `{scale=0.5}` is not correct and doesn't produce the desired effect. If you replace it for `[scale=0.5]` which is the correct syntax, the figure is scaled as desired.

I also suggested to replace `\begin{center}...\end{center}` with `\centering`, but thanks to samcarter, I've learned that `\centering` is a default behaviour in beamer figures.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Lets unfold the box}

\begin{figure}
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]

\draw (0,2.5)                   coordinate[label=above:$H$] (H)
to[short](15,2.5)               coordinate[label=above:$G$] (G)
(0,-2.5)                        coordinate[label=above:$E$] (E)
to[short](15,-2.5)              coordinate[label=above:$F$] (F)
(0,7.5)
to[short](15,7.5)
(0,-7.5)
to[short](15,-7.5)
(15,7.5)
to[short](15,-7.5)
(0,7.5)
to[short](0,-7.5)
(5,2.5)                        coordinate[label=above:$D$] (D)
to[short](5,-2.5)              coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A)
(10,2.5)                       coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C)
to[short](10,-2.5)             coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B);

\fill[orange,opacity=0.4](A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\fill[red,opacity=0.4](A)--(D)--(H)--(E)--cycle;
\fill[blue,opacity=0.4](B)--(C)--(G)--(F)--cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]